# Query cross-account athena aws databases

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

We have two aws accounts - production and staging, each of them having their own athena databases. To run quality checks after deploying to staging, we'd like to run cross account sql queries. What is the best way of achieving this? Currently I export the csv files and compare them in pandas, but being able to query them directly would simplify this.

Comment: You do not technically need to run anything  cross account, you could have a role in both accounts with the right permissions and assume those roles and then query the db from within the account itself.